# Real and imaginary parts of the Fourier transform of a pure cosine wave

Tags: fourier, transform

My understanding of the Fourier transform is that the FT of a cosine wave should be non-zero in the real part and all zero in the imaginary part. This follows from the orthogonality of sine and cosine:

$$
FT(\omega_0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(2\pi \omega_0 t) e^{-i2\pi \omega_0 t} dt =  \\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(2\pi \omega_0 t)\cos(2\pi \omega_0 t) + i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(2\pi \omega_0 t)\sin(2\pi \omega_0 t) dt \\
$$
where
$$
i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(2\pi \omega_0 t)\sin(2\pi \omega_0 t) dt  = 0
$$

However, playing around in Python today I realised this is not the case in the DFT, which has (small) content in the frequency bin of interest (~3.14). What is strange is the size of this does not change with N. Does anyone know what is causing this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100000  # note we need a high N to get good spectral resolution
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=1 / N)

n = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
cos = np.cos(2 * np.pi * n * 2)

COS = np.fft.fft(cos)

print(np.max(np.imag(COS)))  # = ~3.15 at N = 100 and 3.14 at N = 100,000
plt.plot(freqs, np.imag(COS))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent with the OP's mathematical conclusion, a cosine as an even function in time will be completely real in the frequency domain. (An similarly a sine as an odd function in time will be completely imaginary in the frequency domain).

Evaluating the real portion of the `COS` confirms that bin 2 and bin 9,998 are approximately 50,000 in each as expected.

The small non-zero value is at the same bin locations consistent with a small error approximately  $\pi/50,000$ radians. This is due to a repeating of the last sample in the extended periodic repetition of the cosine (similar to the causes of spectral leakage); the last sample in the sequence is the same as the first sample rather than being one sample less. Set `np.linspace` parameter endpoint=False to have a sample sequence that properly circularly repeats without a discontinuity:

```
n = np.linspace(0, 1, N, endpoint=False)
```

This results in the maximum imaginary value to be 1.34e-11 (numerical precision errors), and the maximum real value to be exactly 50,000.